# Installing openssl on CentOS 5.3

Tags: linux, centos, apache-http-server, openssl

I am trying building apache with mod_ssl and I am running into issues becuase my OpenSSL version is less than 0.9.8a. I tried updating but yum says I have the latest version ( 0.9.8e-27.el5_10.1, which already appears to be greater than the required...)

Can I install the latest openssl rpm for CentOS 6.5 distro? What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for the first question is no. It would break your system. I don't know particularly CentOS but it seems doing `yum install mod_ssl` is sufficient to get mod_ssl. If you really need to compile it yourself, you have to install the OpenSSL's development packages: `yum install openssl-devel`.

Comment: I am building apache for a non-root user. `yum install openssl-devel` was what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My Centos 6.5 openssl is at 1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7 (which fyi includes the heartbleed fix) and was installed via yum.

Make sure you have the repo configured and enabled in `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`.
Mine has a stanza like this:

```
#released updates 
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

Then it should simply be a case of `yum update openssl`.
It will inform you of dependencies and prompt you for confirmation before installing anything.